# How do we test Dynamic Type (text size) in an iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

iOS 7 and later allows a user to specify text size in Settings/Display & Brightness/Text Size.  I don't see, or have yet to discover, how to change this in the iOS 7/8 Sim to test my app.  Is it possible? If so, how/where is it done?

Thank you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the simulator, go into settings (Choose "Home" on the hardware menu). Then General->Accessibility->Larger text. You also should slide the switch at the top to "Larger Accessibility Sizes". You'll then get a slider to adjust the text size.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Anyone knows if there is a way to set launch arguments to control dynamic type? That way it can configured in an Xcode Scheme.

Comment: As per the above, I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316591/how-to-test-dynamic-type-larger-font-sizes-in-ios-simulator/38316592#38316592

Comment: Simulator 13.2: **Features -> Increase/Decrease Preferred Text Size** in the menu also have key equivalents.

Comment: You can access this feture from keyboard sortcut: command + option + (plus/minus)

Comment: @Dipak - That shortcut didn't work in the Simulator, it modified the scaling of the Mac. Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 31):

**Xcode 14 onwards**

*Simulator ► Accessibility ► Display & Text Size ► Larger Text ► Select Font.*

As Explained here

https://janeshswift.com/ios/swiftui/how-to-change-text-size-in-an-ios-simulator/

[image]

If you wish to chose font for SwiftUI Preview Select device setting from bottom preview tab.

**Xcode 9.0 onwards**

You can resize font of simulator as -

> *Xcode ► Open developer tool ►  Open accessibility inspector*
> *Select simulator from dropdown after that click **setting(Gear) icon**.*

[image]

Comment: They changed the icon of the Gear but not the position. Works in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer an automatic approach to set this, see this question:
[How to test Dynamic Type (larger font sizes) in iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316591/how-to-test-dynamic-type-larger-font-sizes-in-ios-simulator/38316592#38316592)

Answer (score 1):

The Accessibility Inspector (Xcode/Open Developer Tools/Accessibility Inspector in Xcode 8) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666395/632735) is a great tool for testing Dynamic Fonts and accessibility in general. [The WWDC 2016 video on is is well worth a watch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/407/).